# how to pass checkbox values in an array to a function using onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to pass checkbox values in an array to a function using onclick in JavaScript.
following is my html code. Note that I don't use form tag. only input tags are used.

```
 <input id="a"name="a" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" >A</input>
 <input id="a"name="a" type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked" >B</input>
 <input id="a"name="a" type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" >C</input>
<button onclick="send_query(????)">CLICK</button>
```

following is my JavaScript function

```
function send_query(check) {
var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {

        if (check[i].checked == true) {
            str = str + check[i];
        }
 console.log(str);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure javascript ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wared/9tvQx/)) (tested with Chrome only).

HTML :

```
<button onclick="send_query(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))">
```

Javascript :

```
function send_query(check) {
    var values = [];
    for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        if (check[i].checked == true) {
            values.push(check[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(values.join());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a onclick handler for the button, which can create an array of clicked checkbox values and then call the `send_query` with the parameter as shown below

```
<button onclick="onclickhandler()">CLICK</button>
```

then

```
function onclickhandler() {
    var check = $('input[name="a"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(check);
    send_query(check)
}
```

*Note: I would also recommend using jQuery to register the click handler instead of using inline `onclick` handler*.

*Note: Also `ID` of elements must be unique in a document... you have multiple elements with id `a`, I'm not seeing you using that id anywhere so you could probably remove it*

Comment: but iam passing another input value which is a text through the same call, so with that how can i pass this check box values

Comment: Don't forget `.get()` at the end.

Comment: @Johan yes... `.get().join(',')`

Comment: Yes, if he wants a string. Sounds to me like he wants an array, though.

Comment: Arun i need the onClick function to pass the check box values as an array to a fuction

Comment: @nikki then you write a onclick function where you do this then call the second function from this function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form name="searchForm" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="categorySelect[]" id="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categorySelect[]" id="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="categorySelect[]" id="3"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="send_query();"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
function send_query() {
var check = document.getElementsByName('categorySelect[]');
var selectedRows = [];
for (var i = 0, l = check.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (check[i].checked) {
        selectedRows.push(check[i]);
    }
}

alert(selectedRows.length);
}
```

Comment: i need the onclick function to send the checkbox values to fuction as an array

Comment: check new ans. I think you need this.